# Temporal Left Joins in Flink

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I cannot find any documentation on how to perform left joins on temporal table functions in Flink. All examples describe what seems to be the inner join.

In other words, when I join a table of events onto a temporal table function, I want the result to contain every entry from the left table, regardless of whether there was a match on the temporal table or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed it is not supported as of yet. See [Jingsong Lee's comment in this JIRA ticket](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-14173?focusedCommentId=16936860&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-16936860):

> will affect left outer join(UDTF only support left join), when
> condition is false, should emit data with right null values instead of
> filtering out data

> Zhenghua Gao You are right, we should support it

Do not hesitate to comment on that ticket with your use case. Maybe now that the merge of the Blink planner is more stable there is more time/attention to adding features.

EDIT: You might have more luck with [Temporal Tables](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.11/dev/table/streaming/temporal_tables.html#temporal-table) (as opposed to Temporal Table Functions)